# Execute SQL Server request in the callback of an HttpWebRequest

Tags: windows-phone-7

My understanding is that two `HttpWebRequest` callback can be executed at the same time because the request are asynchronous. However, I want to work with the database on the callback, and it seems not possible with SQL Server. What is the best practice in this case ? Is there a way to add these requests to a queue, or should I use something like mutexes (which I would prefere to avoid, since deadlocks are difficult to debug) ?

edit: My current code doesn't do anything special to prevent that. I fire multiple (different) requests and sometimes in one of the callbacks I get a exception thrown ("Invalid Cross Thread Access") when I try to submit the changes to the database.

I tried to use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` but now I have doubts that it's doing what I want after some googling (I used `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` before successfuly when accessing elements in my XAML, so I thought it could fix my problem accessing the db)

Comment: @ColinE you're right, I should have told you that in the first place. I've updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are doing some heavy computation when your HTTP requests complete, you do not need your callbacks to be executed concurrently. Rather than using the Dispatcher to marshal back onto the UI thread, how about using [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28VS.80%29.aspx) instead? The [DownloadStringCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstringcompleted%28VS.80%29.aspx) that this class raises when the HTTP request is completed is always invoked on the UI thread.

Comment: I switched to HttpWebRequest pretty early in the development of my project for performance reasons. I don't really do serious computation though... Before, I was using SQLite (which handles cross thread access), so maybe that was the origin of the performance problems ? Anyway, can you suggest a less radical solution (I have a lot of HttpWebRequest code...) ?